# What is the differences between server and domain name?

Tags: browser, url

An URL is in the format of:

```
scheme://server:port/pathname
```

What is the differences between server and domain name here? `//superuser.com/questions/ask` is a (relative) URL.

The scheme is omitted (`http:`). The server is `superuser.com`. Maybe the server is equal to the domain name?

Comment: People used to type go to e.g. `http://www.example.com` instead of `http://example.com`. That's because in the *domain* `example.com` (of e.g. an organization), the host known by convention as `www` served the web sites of that organization.

Answer (score 2):

A server is a physical piece of hardware.  This hardware has multiple IP addressess associated with it.  A server is often referenced by referring to one of the IP addresses associated with it, or by the domain name which points to that IP address.

It is worth noting that a server can (and in the case of web sites, usually does) have multiple domains associated with it.

Technically speaking I would argue that it is incorrect to use "server:port" in an HTTP url - it should be domain:port, but it is common practice to do so anyway.   In some addressing schemes (like FTP for example) calling it a server makes sense because there is no difference if the server is referred to by (any) domain associated with it or its IP address.  [ HTTP has additional logic so the server can determine which domain is being referred to ]

Comment: Perhaps you should expand upon the 'L' of "URL" meaning "locator".  The server is identified and _located_ by the host and port in the authority component.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the given example.

In a way, the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) is the server name. But it is the (as the name says) **fully qualified** name. The *name* of the server would be `superuser`, but it lives in the `com` domain. So the full name would be `superuser.com`.

Answer (score 0):

The domain name is a pointer to an IP address which hosts a server. Think of it as the difference between the street address "Example Street 42" (the domain name) and the house on that address (the server). You could argue forever about whether it's more semantically correct to call the domain name `server` or `domain` in an example like that. `server` and `domain` are not equal, but for the purposes of the example, equivalent.

The `//` syntax has a special meaning. It's a shorthand for "choose `http://` or `https://` as appropriate". The background for this syntax is that browsers have security restrictions on loading resources over the http protocol (unencrypted) from a https page (secure). The `//` syntax is beneficial when a server can serve the same content over both http and http. So instead of letting the server or a client side script decide which protocol to use based on the protocol of the requested page, the URL is simply always given as a URL starting with `//` which lets the browser handle this complexity.

For example before this shorthand was invented, you might see code like the following to load Google Analytics on a page that might be served through either http or https:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 

ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') 
+'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

A more modern version of this would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js"></script>
```

Nowadays it's also common for browser to exclude the `http` part of a URL in the address field, presumably to closer match what a typical user actually types into the field. However, the `http` part is still implied in this case. Depending on the browser, this behavior can be turned off so that the `http` part is always shown. And in some browsers, the `http` part becomes visible when you focus the address field.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong.  the "//" means "Start of a network path reference", and is not shorthand for anything. [ See Section 4.2 of RFC3986 ].  The leaving out of the http/https part means that this should be derived from already known information - ie this part is relative.     Also, http or https are only 2 schemes of a very large number of well over 100 accepted schemese - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes

Comment: I'm not talking about the `//` per se. Shorthand refers to the fact that you can omit the `http(s):` part of a URL, in HTML5. What I said should be read in the context of how the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the `host` (which is part of `authority`).

STD 66 (the URI standard) [defines](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.2.2):

> The host subcomponent of authority is identified by an IP literal encapsulated within square brackets, an IPv4 address in dotted- decimal form, or a registered name.
>
> […]
>
> `host        = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name`

(These parts are defined in the linked section "3.2.2. Host".)

**So the `host` can be an IP or a domain name.**

Note that in the URI format you included in your question (which is not the standardized format), it’s not clear what exactly you mean with `server`. A component of the `authority` can also be [user information (`userinfo`)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.2.1), e.g. for providing user name and password for a login.

Answer (score -2):

Server here means its address.

```
http://74.125.224.72/
```

That's one of google's IPs. But I doubt anyone could be told to "74.125.224.72" his answer.

Domain names are just the way to transform IPs into something more human readable like

```
http://google.com/
```

So in both cases you've put the server. First way is its IP and second way is its domain name which is translated on the fly to its IP using DNS.

Comment: "Server here means server IP" is nonsense. Also, Google has *a lot* of IP addresses, 74.125.224.72 is not universal.